# Guide on removing unused Agents and Daemons to speed up MacOS

Tags: performance, daemons, macos, launchd

Can you point me to a good guide on spotting and getting rid of running Agents, Daemons and Processes that aren't useful to me anyway and are taking up memory and CPU cycles?

Comment: With launchd and virtual memory, you will be hard pressed to find anything that isn't used yet impacts RAM or CPU. Are you looking for Activity Monitor to just see what usage is?

Comment: By not used, I meant not useful to me. There may be updaters for software I don't care, or services I don't use.

Comment: Then you should have a look at the manpage for launchctl. you can get a list and unload all of the ones you don't need.